# (ASP.NET MVC) Criar variavel Session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, iis

Tenho uma aplicação ASP.NET MVC que está publicada em dois servidores IIS (homologação e produção);

Nesta aplicação, uso a variavel de Sessão para guardar o login do usuário em uma parte dela, porém, no servidor de produção não está funcionando a criação da variavel Session, me retornando o erro: `object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Acredito que possa ser alguma configuração no IIS porquê o mesmo código funciona no servidor de homologação e também em localhost, por isso, não consigo debugar.

Nunca fiz configuração em IIS, mas ao estudar brevemente sobre isso, encontrei que existe uma configuração para Session State, conforme imagem abaixo, porém, por default, já vem configurado como True e mesmo alterando para False, continua o mesmo erro.

Segue linha de código para analise:

```
// POST: Auth/Login/{login}
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(DTOViewModel login)
{
    try
    {
        this.Autenticar(login.Usuario, login.Senha);
        Session["user"] = login.Usuario; // <---- aqui que está dando problema
        return Json(new { url = Url.Action("Index", "Usuario/Home") });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(new { erro = ex.Message });
    }
}
```

Segue imagem de configuração do IIS:

[image: Definição de Sessão no IIS]

Obrigado a quem puder ajudar.
:)

Comment: Me parece um comportamento comum de balanceamento, você pode estar criando a sessão em um servidor e o próximo request é respondido pelo outro, onde essa sessão não foi criada.

Comment: Não sei se entendi direito a sua resposta @LeandroAngelo, poderia esclarecer para mim? Pelo que eu entendi a variável de sessão pode não ter sido criada neste momento da aplicação, mas o que me confunde é no servidor de homologação funciona normalmente.

Comment: Esquece, tinha lido errado o início da sua pergunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caso alguém venha a ter o mesmo problema que eu tive, vou deixar documentado a solução:

Fiz a mesma pergunta no Stack Oveflow em inglês e segue o link com a solução:
[Solução](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48402241/cant-create-session-in-asp-mvc)

Basicamente, a alteração que deve ser feita no `web.config`

```
<configuration> 
    <system.webServer>
        <modules>
          <remove name="Session" />
          <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>
        </modules>   
    </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```